# Wordpress wp_head() title tag not working

Tags: php, wordpress, seo

The problem is that on my one pager website the title tag doesn't get populated.

`page.php` looks like this:

```
<?php 

locate_template( 'page-home.php', true );

exit();
```

`page-home.php` looks like this:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php get_template_part('template-sections/slider'); ?>

<?php get_template_part('template-sections/services'); ?>

<?php //etc. ?>

<?php get_footer();
```

`header.php` looks like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
    <link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11"/>
    <base href="<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/">
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>

<body itemprop="hasPart" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage" <?php body_class(); ?>>
<!-- etc -->
```

And `footer.php` looks like this:

```
            <?php wp_footer(); ?>
    </main>
    <aside class="aside">
        <div class="aside__content">
        </div>
    </aside>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Yes. There is a page present called `home` in the backend. And I would like Wordpress to pick that title up and use it as a title tag in `header.php`.

Now as far as I know, Wordpress normally automatically populates the title tag. So what's the problem here? Thanks!

PS: I am not using the `wp_title` filter anywhere in my custom Wordpress theme.

Comment: What data does the title on that page contain, is it blank? Do you have YoastSEO installed? If you enable the stock Twenty17 theme does the issue persist?

Comment: I had 'All In One SEO Pack' installed. But already disabled it... same problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok, the **solution I found** might help others. So I felt free to post it here.

Part 1. Comparing with the standard `twentyseventeen` theme. I found that Wordpress needs `add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );` to be able to manage the title. (Otherwise you should just add a `<title>` tag yourself in `header.php`, I guess.

Part 2. I needed to add a **custom filter** to `functions.php` to display the title in a format that is desired. For example (using a SEO plugin):

```
function custom_title( $title_parts ) {
    $page_id   = site_get_page_id(); // custom function, you might want to use global $post here
    $seo_title = @get_post_meta( $page_id, '_aioseop_title' );

    if ( isset( $seo_title[0] ) ) {
        $title = $seo_title[0];
    } elseif ( isset( $page_id ) ) {
        $title = get_the_title( $page_id );
    }

    $page_title           = isset( $title ) ? $title : 'Page not found in backend';
    $title_parts['title'] = $page_title;

    return $title_parts;
}
```

Comment: forgot about the theme support, thanks!